# What should HTTP 201 response body be when responding to a POST request with large data?

Tags: python, http, fastapi, httpresponse

I have a server implemented using FastAPI in Python, and I am **sending large data (~2 GB) to the server** via a `POST` request. Once the request is processed on the server side, I would like to return a `201 "Created"` response to the client.

A `201` response should have a body, so I should not send a response with an empty body (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST), but at the same time, I **don't want to send back the newly created resource as it is so large**, and the client doesn't need the resource at the point of the `POST` request. Alternatively, I would be tempted to respond with a `204 "No Content"`, but it doesn't seem to be the recommended response for a successful `POST` request.

So assuming a `201` response is sent, **what should be the body of the response to avoid large data sent back for no reason?**

Here is a minimal code describing my issue, currently returning a `201` response with an empty body:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException, Response, status

app = FastAPI()


@app.post("/data", status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
async def send_data(data, response: Response):
    try:
        # process data on the server
        # ...
        pass
    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, e)
    return response  # response with empty body
```

Comment: There is no need to return the resource created. rfc9110: "The 201 response content typically describes and links to the resource(s) created." . Return whatever you'd like, but something indicating the length of the received data (and if you need it, a checksum or something similar) and a `Location` header that links to the resource is probably more than good enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/201)

> #### `201 Created`
>
> The HTTP `201 Created` success status response code indicates that the request has succeeded and has led to the creation
> of a resource. The new resource, **or a description and link to the new
> resource**, is effectively created before the response is sent back and
> the newly created items are returned in the body of the message,
> located at either the URL of the request, or at the URL in the value
> of the [`Location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Location) header.
>
> The common use case of this status code is as the result of a
> [`POST`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) request.

Similarly, as described in [RFC 9110: HTTP Semantics](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110#status.201)

> The `201 (Created)` status code indicates that the request has been
> fulfilled and has resulted in one or more new resources being created.
> The primary resource created by the request is **identified by** either a
> [`Location`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110#field.location) header field in the response or, if no `Location`
> header field is received, by the target URI.
>
> The **201 response content typically describes and links to the
> resource(s) created**. Any validator fields ([Section 8.8](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110#response.validator)) sent in the
> response convey the current validators for a new representation
> created by the request. Note that the PUT method ([Section 9.3.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110#PUT)) has
> additional requirements that might preclude sending such validators.

Hence, in short, one does **not really have to return the actual data** of the resource created back to the client, but rather **a description and/or a link to the new resource in the [`Location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Location) header would be sufficient**. The description in the response, among others, could include the length of the data received by the server, thus informing the user that the upload was indeed successful.